# Why Outlook 2007 saved message (.msg) loose text when i click Forward?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

i've the following problem: if i save an message from Outlook 2007 (.msg), then i open the .msg file and click "Forward", Outlook create a new mail WITHOUT the message text. 
It is very annoying to copy and paste the text inside the new mail. 
Is it a common problem ? Is there a solution for it ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the case with all messages you save externally?  What happens if you try to forward an email in Outlook that has not been saved to an external file?

Perhaps you just don't have the option set to include the original text in a Forwarded message.

[image]

What normally happens when an Outlook email is saved externally as a .msg file, then opened, is that it comes up exactly as if you had opened it while it was still in the Outlook data file.  It shows the same display of the contents and the same ribbon toolbar with Reply, Forward, etc.

If this isn't what happens when you save an email externally, I would look at the process you're using to save it.  Are you using File/Save As?  Are you choosing .msg as the file format?